# How can I get my text animation to display?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on building a website for my CV and I tried to make my homepage a bit more interesting by animation the welcome message. I used https://codepen.io/alvarotrigo/pen/ZEJgqLN this codepen as a reference. When I try importing this into my own file. I get the "Uncaught ReferenceError ReferenceError: $ is not defined. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```js
var words = ['Welcome to my CV'],
    part,
    i = 0,
    offset = 0,
    len = words.length,
    forwards = true,
    skip_count = 0,
    skip_delay = 15,
    speed = 70;
var wordflick = function () {
  setInterval(function () {
    if (forwards) {
      if (offset >= words[i].length) {
        ++skip_count;
        if (skip_count == skip_delay) {
          forwards = false;
          skip_count = 0;
        }
      }
    }
    else {
      if (offset == 0) {
        forwards = true;
        i++;
        offset = 0;
        if (i >= len) {
          i = 0;
        }
      }
    }
    part = words[i].substr(0, offset);
    if (skip_count == 0) {
      if (forwards) {
        offset++;
      }
      else {
        offset--;
      }
    }
    $('.word').text(part);
  },speed);
};

$(document).ready(function () {
  wordflick();
});
```

```css
html {
    font-family:system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
}

body {
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    font-size: 150%;
}

.container {
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 10px;
}

.header {
    display: grid;
}

.navbar {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    gap: 100px;
}

.navbar-item {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: black;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
}

.navbar-item:hover {
    color: orange; 
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.welcome-message {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 100px;
}

footer {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header">
            <h1>John Smith</h1>
            <div class="navbar">
                <div class="navbar-item"><a href="landing.html">Home</a></div>
                <div class="navbar-item"><a href="about.html">About me</a></div>
                <div class="navbar-item"><a href="education.html">Education</a></div>
                <div class="navbar-item"><a href="experience.html">Experience</a></div>
                <div class="navbar-item"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="welcome-container">
            <div class="word"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <footer>John Smith Smith</footer>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

main.js: 44"

Comment: Do you have jQuery or whatever the original code uses?

Answer (score -1):

You will need to include jQuery to use the $.
In codepen you can include it in the settings for the javascript, but you could probably include it as an external script in the HTML.

This is the URL alvarotrigo used for the external jquery script
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js